# Url based wildcard redirect with exempted url

Tags: php

I'm no PHP expert. Just want to know if this is possible.

I'm trying to exempt a url from a php wildcard redirect but I am not able to add the exemption.

I used php case switch

Here's my current code.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch($uri)
{
    case '/admin':
    header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/admin-page?Redirect');
    break;
    case $uri != '/':
    header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
    break;
}
```

Was hoping exempt the url/admin from the wildcard redirect but even that gets redirected.

Comment: Add an if statement inside your `case $uri != '/':`: `if ($uri != '/admin'){...`

Comment: Thanks I think I got it :)

Comment: _“Add an if statement inside your case”_ - that’s a terrible way to use `switch` … This should rather handle the `/` case separately (if only by doing _nothing_, if that is the desired action), and then leave everything else up to the `default` branch.

Comment: Actually it still gets redirected any other options?